# Restricting AddJwtBearer from validating ID Tokens in .net core 3.1

Tags: .net-core, oauth-2.0

I implemented Token validation in .net core 3.1 application as below :

```
        services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.Authority = Configuration["AuthorityUrl"];
            options.Audience = Configuration["Audience"];
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                NameClaimType = "preferred_username"
            };
        });
```

My main issue now which is security threat I believe that if the user passes ID token the authentication passes successfully which is wrong as Resource servers should accept only Access token. Is this behavior is right ? if yes how can limit the validation to Access tokens only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your API's job is to verify the attributes of the token - and APIs are typically configured with fixed values for items 2 and 3 below:

- Signature
- Issuer
- Audience
- Expiry
- Scope

Use of id tokens should naturally fail if you check the audience (and you should) - where typical values are shown below:

- Audience of access token = api.mycompany.com
- Audience of id token = mywebclientid

APIs should also check for a required scope - and Authorization Servers do not include scopes in id tokens - since scopes are only used by APIs to protect areas of data.

In addition, some providers will provide a claim within the token to tell you its type, though this is vendor specific. As an example, Curity provide a 'purpose' claim - see the [example at the end f this document](https://curity.io/resources/develop/claims/scopes-claims-and-the-client/).

Comment: You are right, I  also used curity for 2 years and it had the purpose claim which helped me to detect but not the other providers. Thanks for your help